# On a redash dashboard, what causes "Error running query: 100035 (22007): Timestamp 'd_yesterday' is not recognized"?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, redash

On a Redash application instance backed by a Snowflake database, I've got a dashboard set up with a number of queries, each of which take a parameter of type `date` named `startDate`.

Each of my queries are coded to apply the dashboard's selected date via WHERE clauses like:

```
WHERE created_at >= '{{ startDate }}'
```

In most cases, this is working fine.

However, when on my dashboard, for the `startDate` parameter, I select the special value `Yesterday` (instead of a specific date), some (but not all) of my queries display an error instead of displaying any data: `Error running query: 100035 (22007): Timestamp 'd_yesterday' is not recognized`.

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when on the affected queries, the parameter still has its default type of `text`, instead of having been changed to type `date`.

The error is occurring because choosing the special date value "Yesterday" on the dashboard only works with date-type parameters -- not text-type parameters.

Changing the parameter type to `date` on each of the individual queries, saving those changes, and then refreshing the dashboard, should fix the problem.

Comment: and speaking to the error message, it's expecting a string that can be parsed as a date thus 'YYYY-MM-DD' type thing, and 'd_yesterday` does not match the default date format of the session/user.